# Java obtener datos para un objeto de un arreglo de cadenas en el constructor

Tags: java, array, constructor

Hola buenas tengo una duda con el constructor, le paso un vector de Strings, y quiero que dentro del constructor se recorra esa matriz y que en cada iteracion se guarde en distintos sitios.

```
    public Noticia(String[] vector) {//El vetor tiene 4 posiciones [0,1,2,3,4] y dentro hay palabras

for(//no sé muy bien como poner la condición no se si estaría bien int i=0; i <5; i++){
     if(i){
variable = vector[i];
//Es que si lo pongo así en cada iteracion del for se cargaría lo que esta dentro de la variable

y quiero hacer esto:
//si es la primera posición guardarla en una variable de tipo String Variable1         
//si es la segunda posición guardarla en otra variable de tipo String variable2

     }
//y ya no sabría que poner dentro del constructor: 
this.variable1 = variable1 ;
this.variable2 = variable2;
//No sabría si esto se puede hacer y de si estaría bien.
}
```

¿Se podría poner así?

Las posiciones del vector contienen palabras de tamaño variable y no sé que tamaño tiene.

Podría hacerlo asi:¿?

```
public Noticia(String[] vector) {

        for(int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                title = vector[i];
            }else if(i == 1) {
                category = vector[i];
            }else if(i == 2) {
                description = vector[i];
            }else if(i == 3) {
                author = vector[i];
            }else {
                date = vector[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

cada variable es de tipo String, despues tengo getters, setters y un toString de cada variable.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad lo que intentas hacer no tiene mucho sentido, ya que puedes acceder a ese array con 0,1,2,3... No es necesario separarlos en variables independientes. Lo mejor seria almacenar ese array de palabras en una variable privada de tipo String[], y ya en la clase hacer métodos para que tengas que hacer lo que necesites con esas palabras.

```
class Noticia {
private String[] palabrasNoticia;
public Noticia(String[] vector){
    this.palabrasNoticia = vector;
}
```

}

Comenta que querrias hacer con esas palabras y te puedo ayudar.

Comment: lo que quiero es que me las guarde en distintas variables, por que son palabras distintas y necesito hacer get y set con cada variable. y un toString para que me lo devuelva. for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if(i = 0) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    titulo = vector[i];
   }else if(i = 1) {
    this.categoria = categoria;

Comment: Siempre son la misma cantidad de palabras?

Comment: Como tienes que hacer una cosa para cada elemento del array, no es necesario hacer un FOR. Lo mejor sera this.title = vector[0]; this.category = vector[1] etc...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que en realidad necesitas es cambiar el enfoque... tienes un objeto noticia que recibe un array de strings que se corresponden con title, category, description, author y date.  Por lo tanto, tu objeto noticia debe tener esos atributos y recibirlos por constructor:

```
class News {

    private String title;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String author;
    private String date;

    public News(String title, String category, String description, String author, String date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.author = author;
        this.date = date
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```